# cakephp refresh view from controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP. Supposed to be a simple task, but I run into problems. I have a controller that puts records into the database from traversing a given directory - all goes well. Now in the view, I want to display the progress of the operation (there are thousands of records, so it will last some time).

I already have a counter (`$countFound`, `$countSaved`, `$countDiff`) in the controller and set these to output in the view, but it isn't updating. I tried

```
$this->Session->setFlash()
```

from within the loop, but these flashes get displayed only once the operation has completed.

Comment: PHP cannot do things like progress bars on its own because once a PHP-only page is loaded it cannot change.  Progress bars are normally written also using Javascript.  However, when you're doing an operation that takes a particularly long time to execute, especially if there's no limit to how big the operation can be, you should consider that PHP has a maximum execution time such that your script will just get cut off if it takes too long.  In short, PHP pages aren't really intended to do big operations like that.  So you may want to reconsider your design.

Comment: @Kai, thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't need to be a progress bar; displaying the number of saved records will suffice. Execution time is not an issue in this case.

Comment: I totally understand that you're displaying a number rather than an actual bar, but the same still mostly applies, since it's kind of just another way of displaying a "progress bar" if you know what I mean?  You'll need to save the state of your current # of files somewhere as it works, like in session or your database, then you'll need a controller action where it displays that number.  Then on the page you kick off the operation, use javascript to fetch that progress page at regular intervals and display it somehow.

Comment: Kai, thanks for your explanation! I saw that CakePHP can do with jQuery. I will try that. Have a nice evening! - olli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Javascript and Ajax with some custom methods in your controller to simulate RealTime update in your view.

Try using Jquery's ajax method to check periodically if there's a new record (setInterval + $.ajax wich will provide the last displayed record to the custom controller method, the controller method check if there's any new records if so it returns it or nothing, meanwhile in Jquery's ajax callback process the result of the controller method and display the records if there's any)

something like this

```
    setInterval(function(){
      $.get(url, {lastrecordID:_id}, function(data){
        if(data !== "undefined") // append to the dom 
             dom.append(data).fadeIn();
      });
    },250);
```

url, _id and dom are js data that you should fill dynamically depending on the context.

If you want the only show the number of records then ask for the new records each xx millisecond and update the field

```
var dom = $('.directoriesCount');
setInterval(function(){
          $.get('directories/countupdate', {}, function(data){
            dom.empty().append(data);
          });
        },250);
```

And in  Directories controller :

```
public function countupdate() {
    return $this->Directory->find('count');
}
```

I didn't take performance into account, so if the view containing is frequently used you might want to optimize the count query or increase the interval between updates.

Comment: thank you mohamed, this approach works well for me. I was even able to massively speed up the Controller-action by using CakePHP's 'saveMany()' outside of the Controllers loop. thanks again!